# Twitter class by Tijs Verkoyen

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to use this class http://classes.verkoyen.eu/twitter/ to update status on twitter, but I am getting this error:

```
/statuses/update.xml Could not authenticate you.
```

My code is just the following, I am using the latest version of the class (1.0.5)

```
<?php
include "twitter.php";
$twit = new Twitter("username","password");
$twit->updateStatus("Testing");
?>
```

Comment: Why not post a comment on the author's blog? By the looks of it, Tijs responds pretty quickly to comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling safe_mode in your php.ini file?

```
safe_mode off
```